# viewWillAppear equivalent in background mode

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, background, viewwillappear

The workflow of my app is when I lost connection I redirect the app to a specific `viewController`, then on the `viewWillAppear` I do some treatment.

In the `foreground` mode this works perfectly.

In the `background` mode, the redirection is performed, but the `viewWillAppear` is not fired.

Is there any equivalent for `viewWillAppear` or any other way to check if the `viewController` has appeared while on `background`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in background the view is not shown: this is why i guess the viewWillApperar is not called.

I suggest you to move the code/check you need to do in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller, which is called after being loaded into memory.

Comment: The view is already loaded, so `viewDidLoad` is not going to be called :(

Comment: `viewDidLoad` fire only once